# Are posts supposed to look like this?

Tags: bug, design

Are all the votes supposed to be on top of the question instead of on the side? Is this because I am using a different computer or is everyone experiencing this?

[image: The vote count, favorite icon, and timeline icon are centered between the question title and the body.]

Occurring in Chrome on Mac OS 10.8.5. I am using an old computer because I forgot my good computer at home.

Comment: I added browser and OS as text to the question but version numbers would be helpful. I'm not duplicating the issue in Firefox 72.0.1 (64-bit)/macOS 10.15.2.

Comment: FWIW I see this on old, no longer supported browsers, such as Internet Explorer. So, yes, it's because of the old computer :-)

Comment: The screenshot could benefit from some [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)